# Virtual method is faster than non virtual method?

Tags: c#, performance

Recently I read about the [Measure Early and Often for Performance, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507639.aspx), it comes with the [source code](http://measureitdotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0fc8656e5f76#MeasureIt.cs) and [binary](http://nuget.org/packages/MeasureIt.exe/).

Extracts from the article: "I stressed that to reliably create high-performance programs, you need to understand the performance of the individual components you use early in the design process".

So, I used his tool (v0.2.2) to benchmark and try to see the performance of the individual components.

Under my PC (x64), the results are as follows:

```
Name                                                                            Median  Mean    StdDev  Min     Max Samples
NOTHING [count=1000]                                                            0.14    0.177   0.164   0       0.651   10
MethodCalls: EmptyStaticFunction() [count=1000 scale=10.0]                      1       1.005   0.017   0.991   1.042   10
Loop 1K times [count=1000]                                                      85.116  85.312  0.392   84.93   86.279  10
MethodCalls: EmptyStaticFunction(arg1,...arg5) [count=1000 scale=10.0]          1.163   1.172   0.015   1.163   1.214   10
MethodCalls: aClass.EmptyInstanceFunction() [count=1000 scale=10.0]             1.009   1.011   0.019   0.995   1.047   10
MethodCalls: aClass.Interface() [count=1000 scale=10.0]                         1.112   1.121   0.038   1.098   1.233   10
MethodCalls: aSealedClass.Interface() (inlined) [count=1000 scale=10.0]         0       0.008   0.025   0       0.084   10
MethodCalls: aStructWithInterface.Interface() (inlined) [count=1000 scale=10.0] 0       0.008   0.025   0       0.084   10
MethodCalls: aClass.VirtualMethod() [count=1000 scale=10.0]                     0.674   0.683   0.025   0.674   0.758   10
MethodCalls: Class.ReturnsValueType() [count=1000 scale=10.0]                   2.165   2.16    0.033   2.107   2.209   10
```

I am surprised to see that virtual method (0.674) is faster than non virtual instance method (1.009) or static method (1). And interface is not too slow at all! (i would expect interface to be at least 2x as slow).

Since this results come from a trusted source, I am wondering how to explain the the above findings.

I don't think the article is outdated being a problem, as in the article itself it doesn't say anything regarding the readings. All it did was to provide a tool to benchmark.

Comment: Considering that interfaces are an almost entirely source code level construct, why would you expect that to cost 50% or more performance during runtime?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Because virtual method call takes 2 instructions, while interface takes at least 4

Comment: an interface call *is* a virtual call

Comment: The article you linked almost certainly meant to measure the performance of your own code, not the mechanics of calling it.  The ability to decide between the features of virtual or non-virtual calls is almost certainly going to be vastly more important than any miniscule difference in performance.

Comment: one thing to watch on that blog entry: it is May 2008. A lot can change in 5 years.

Comment: The only thing we keep an eye on for performance up front these days is LINQ, but only because we have an unhealthy infatuation with it... The rest is profiled to identify hot spots.

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with the tenet "Measure Early and Often for Performance". IMO, correctness should be valued above all other qualities. Optimisation is something that comes last.

Comment: Measuring especially when you get the level of virtual calls or method invocation is tricky.  The cost of a cache line flush could be far more than your method call. The noise from the operating environment is so great compared to what you measure.

Comment: @spender that depends on what you are doing. I think that blog is meant more for library authors than application developers. There can be a very different mind-set when working in library code.

Comment: @spender I mostly agree with you, but sometimes a bit of up-front thought needs to go into some sections of code that are going to be doing a lot of work, or called many times etc. Granted, most performance issues we encounter can be fixed afterwards, but sometimes we hit a problem that incurs a larger refactoring. The trick is to preempt just those I suppose :-)

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't think an interface call is identical to a virtual call on x86. At least in my (potentially flawed) benchmark it cost 7 cycles compared to 4 for a virtual call. But as always, performance is tricky business and CPUs and compilers often exhibit non intuitive performance.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess that the benchmarking methodology used in his example is flawed. The following code, run in LINQPad, shows about what you'd expect:

```
/* This is a benchmarking template I use in LINQPad when I want to do a
 * quick performance test. Just give it a couple of actions to test and
 * it will give you a pretty good idea of how long they take compared
 * to one another. It's not perfect: You can expect a 3% error margin
 * under ideal circumstances. But if you're not going to improve
 * performance by more than 3%, you probably don't care anyway.*/
void Main()
{
    // Enter setup code here
    var foo = new Foo();
    var actions = new[]
    {
        new TimedAction("control", () =>
        {
            // do nothing
        }),
        new TimedAction("non-virtual instance", () =>
        {
            foo.DoSomething();
        }),
        new TimedAction("virtual instance", () =>
        {
            foo.DoSomethingVirtual();
        }),
        new TimedAction("static", () =>
        {
            Foo.DoSomethingStatic();
        }),
    };
    const int TimesToRun = 10000000; // Tweak this as necessary
    TimeActions(TimesToRun, actions);
}

public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething() {}
    public virtual void DoSomethingVirtual() {}
    public static void DoSomethingStatic() {}
}


#region timer helper methods
// Define other methods and classes here
public void TimeActions(int iterations, params TimedAction[] actions)
{
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    int length = actions.Length;
    var results = new ActionResult[actions.Length];
    // Perform the actions in their initial order.
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var action = actions[i];
        var result = results[i] = new ActionResult{Message = action.Message};
        // Do a dry run to get things ramped up/cached
        result.DryRun1 = s.Time(action.Action, 10);
        result.FullRun1 = s.Time(action.Action, iterations);
    }
    // Perform the actions in reverse order.
    for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var action = actions[i];
        var result = results[i];
        // Do a dry run to get things ramped up/cached
        result.DryRun2 = s.Time(action.Action, 10);
        result.FullRun2 = s.Time(action.Action, iterations);
    }
    results.Dump();
}

public class ActionResult
{
    public string Message {get;set;}
    public double DryRun1 {get;set;}
    public double DryRun2 {get;set;}
    public double FullRun1 {get;set;}
    public double FullRun2 {get;set;}
}

public class TimedAction
{
    public TimedAction(string message, Action action)
    {
        Message = message;
        Action = action;
    }
    public string Message {get;private set;}
    public Action Action {get;private set;}
}

public static class StopwatchExtensions
{
    public static double Time(this Stopwatch sw, Action action, int iterations)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            action();
        }
        sw.Stop();

        return sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Results:

```
                       DryRun1 DryRun2  FullRun1 FullRun2
 control               0.0361  0        47.82    47.1971 
 non-virtual instance  0.0858  0.0004   69.6178  68.7508 
 virtual instance      0.1676  0.0004   70.5103  69.2135 
 static                0.1138  0        66.6182  67.0308
```

#### Conclusion

These results indicate that a method call to a virtual instance takes only *slightly* longer (by maybe 2-3%, after accounting for the control) than a regular instance method call, which takes only slightly longer than a static call. That's about what I would expect.

#### Update

I did some more playing around after @colinfang commented about adding a `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` attribute to my methods, and all I can conclude is that micro-optimization is complicated. Here are some observations:

- As @colinfang says, adding NoInlining to the methods does yield results more like what he described. It's not surprising that method inlining is one way the system can optimize non-virtual methods to go faster than virtual methods. But it is surprising that not inlining would actually make virtual methods take *longer* than non-virtual ones.
- If I compile with `/optimize+`, the non-virtual instance call actually takes less time than the control, by over 20%.
- If I eliminate the lambda functions, and pass the method group directly like so:

  ```
  new TimedAction("non-virtual instance", foo.DoSomething),
  new TimedAction("virtual instance", foo.DoSomethingVirtual),
  new TimedAction("static", Foo.DoSomethingStatic),
  ```

  ... then virtual and non-virtual calls end up taking about the same amount of time as each other, but the static method call takes significantly longer (upwards of 20%).

So yeah, weird stuff. The point is: when you get down to this level of optimizations, unexpected results will appear due to any number of optimizations at the compiler, JIT, or even hardware level. The differences we're seeing may be the result of something as uncontrollable as the CPU's L2 caching strategy. Here be dragons.

Comment: Would you mind adding `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` to all of your methods under `Foo`? after adding it I am able to reproduce similar results as in my post.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why counter-intuitive results could come out. One reason is that virtual calls sometimes (possibly most of the time) emit a `callvirt` IL instruction, to ensure a null check (probably when searching for the vtable). On the other hand, if the JIT can tell for sure that only one specific implementation is going to be called at a virtual call spot (and on a not-null reference), it will most probably try turn it to a static call.

I think this is one of the few things that really shouldn't matter in your application design. You should be considering virtual/sealed a language construct, not a runtime one (let the runtime do what it can do best). If a method needs to be virtual for your application's needs, make it virtual. If it doesn't need to be virtual, don't make it. And if you are, indeed, *not* going to base the design on your application on this, then there's no need to benchmark it. (Except curiosity.)

Comment: The C# compiler uses `callvirt` for almost all calls to instance methods, whether or not the target method is virtual. The one exception I know is when you use `base.Foo(...)` to explicitly call a base class implementation.

Comment: @280Z28 Which, funnily enough, does not appear to be permitted by the spec: the spec requires a null check even for `base.Foo(...)` calls (which can be called with a `null` `this` only if they're called, directly or indirectly, from other languages than C#). I'm pretty sure that's a bug in the spec, not a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @hvd `base.Foo(...)` requires direct dispatch to a specific method, even (especially) if that method has been overridden. If it used `callvirt`, you'd end up with the method calling itself over and over.

Comment: @280Z28 The spec doesn't say anything about `call`/`callvirt`, the spec says a method call on `null` causes a `NullReferenceException`. No relevant exceptions. I know `call` doesn't cause a `NullReferenceException`, but that just means `call` is insufficient, and a conforming C# compiler is *supposed* to emit an explicit null check and a throw a manually created `NullReferenceException` before using `call`. (Again, a sane implementation will not do that, but technically, the spec does say it has to.)